# How to make a Depth First Search Work with a (node, list) relationship instead of (node, node) in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I am having difficulty with turning the code below which works with a s(a,b), s(a,c) type relationship into code that would work with s(a, [b,c]) type relationships, as I am new to prolog I cannot figure out the logic behind it even as [H|_] will not work, (I have been looking through trace) and any help would be gladly appreciated!
Here is my base code:

```
% solve( Node, Solution):
%    Solution is an acyclic path (in reverse order) between Node and a goal

solve( Node, Solution)  :-
  depthfirst( [], Node, Solution).

% depthfirst( Path, Node, Solution):
%   extending the path [Node | Path] to a goal gives Solution

depthfirst( Path, Node, [Node | Path] )  :-
   goal(Node).

depthfirst( Path, Node, Sol)  :-
  s( Node, Node1),
  \+ member( Node1, Path),                % Prevent a cycle
  depthfirst( [Node | Path], Node1, Sol).

depthfirst2( Node, [Node], _)  :-
   goal( Node).

depthfirst2( Node, [Node | Sol], Maxdepth)  :-
   Maxdepth > 0,
   s( Node, Node1),
   Max1 is Maxdepth - 1,
   depthfirst2( Node1, Sol, Max1).


goal(f).
goal(j).
s(a,b).
s(a,c).
s(b,d).
s(b,e).
s(c,f).
s(c,g).
s(d,h).
s(e,i).
s(e,j).
```

The code above works as solve(a, Sol). returns: Sol = [j, e, b, a] Put simply I cannot get the code to work with

```
goal(f).
goal(j).
s(a,[b, c]).
s(b,[d, e]).
s(c,[f, g]).
s(d,[h]).
s(e,[i, j]).
```

Instead of

```
goal(f).
goal(j).
s(a,b).
s(a,c).
s(b,d).
s(b,e).
s(c,f).
s(c,g).
s(d,h).
s(e,i).
s(e,j).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you query `s/2` in the original code, you query `s/2`, and use `member/2` to pick an element from the list:

```
solve( Node, Solution)  :-
  depthfirst( [], Node, Solution).

depthfirst( Path, Node, [Node | Path])  :-
   goal(Node).

depthfirst( Path, Node, Sol)  :-
  s(Node, Nodes1), member(Node1, Nodes1),
  \+ member(Node1, Path),                % Prevent a cycle
  depthfirst([Node | Path], Node1, Sol).

depthfirst2( Node, [Node], _)  :-
   goal(Node).

depthfirst2( Node, [Node | Sol], Maxdepth)  :-
   Maxdepth > 0,
   s(Node, Nodes1), member(Node1, Nodes1),
   Max1 is Maxdepth - 1,
   depthfirst2( Node1, Sol, Max1).
```

That being said, it is not very common to work with such lists in the facts, since it makes querying harder. For example it is harder to query for nodes that have an edge to a node `f` for example.

Comment: Very well formatted and explained! Thank you I will mark this as solved